# store value in code behind from cloned jquery textbox value

Tags: c#, jquery, textbox

I have a button to clone a textbox, which allow the user to type in too

jquery

```
function generateRow() {
if (totalans == 9) {
    $('#<%= label2.ClientID %>').html('<b>Maximum of 10 answers per questions reached</b>');
}
else {
    totalans = totalans + 1; // same as totalans++;
     $("#ans").clone().attr({id: "ans_clone_" + totalans, name: "ans_clone_" + totalans}).prependTo("#ans2");
     // then you can loop through each input using the totalans variable.
}
```

Now, I have no idea on how to retrieve those textbox in codebehind c#. 
As I want to store it inside the database.

I have got some help from someone here, but it still couldnt help me.

```
for(x=0; x<totalans; x++){ var tVal = $('#ans_clone_' + x).val(); //process }
```

im using vs2010, DotNet.

Comment: I hope comments like `// same as totalans++;` are not present in any of your code that is actually used. These are the worst kind of comments - everyone who knows the languages **knows** what a certain line of code does, so never explain what a specific line of code does but what it's used for (and the only if it's important)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `HiddenField` server control onto page and use it to store count of dynamically added textboxes. Then, on post back parse it's value and fetch dynamically added textboxes values from `Request.Params` collection:

```
function addAnswer() {
     var hfAnswers = $("#<%= hfDynamicAnswers.ClientID %>");
     var answers = parseInt(hfAnswers.val()) + 1;
     hfAnswers.val(answers);

     $("#<%= tbAnswer.ClientID %>").clone().attr({ name: "ans_clone_" + answers, id: "ans_clone_" + answers }).appendTo("#answersContainer");
}

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfDynamicAnswers" Value="0" />
<div id="answersContainer">
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbAnswer" />
     <input type="button" value="Add Answer" onclick="addAnswer()" />
</div>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var answers = int.Parse(hfDynamicAnswers.Value);
    for (int i = 1; i <= answers; i++)
    {
        var answer = Request.Params["ans_clone_" + i.ToString()];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET should automatically serialize all your controls for you when you post them back.  Just make sure they have unique ids.

```
Request.Form["ans_clone_" + i]
```